# I need some insight on PDF Bookmarks

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I haven't done any programming to handle PDFs in depth, only PDF creation with PHP.

I've been asked into a project where the requirements are generating PDF bookmarks with titles created from selected text.

The scenario goes like this:

- The user highlights some text in a given PDF file.
- The user is prompted to enter the starting page number for the chapter (bookmark)
- A bookmark is created with a title  which points to the given page number.
- Multi-level bookmarks to handle sub-chapters (like child nodes) should be supported.

Due to some restraints, the client would prefer this to be a web app ***if possible***.

What platform/language/technology/library would you recommend?

Is it doable in a browser? Should this be a desktop app instead?

I am fluent in PHP/Javascript and capable in Python with tiny bits of experience on handling PDF files (nothing further than generating formatted PDF). (plus willing to learn anything new)

I've got some time to dig around and conceptualise it, so I'm very open to suggestions.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: In java and c# there is a library called iText. Also in java an apache project called pdfbox. These libraries allow lots of manipulation of PDF files.